# Removing the need for pathing in cloudFront distribution of S3 bucket requiring .html at the end of the page name, in Next.js project

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Next.js, React, Ts project that exists on a S3 bucket as a static site and is distributed via cloudFront.

The problem I'm running into is for me to go a different page I have to append .html at the end of the page name.

So `mysite.com/profile` will return a `<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>` error, however `mysite.com/profile.html` will route me correctly.

Is there some way to remove this necessity?

If this is a next issue i'm using

```
npx next build
npx next export
```

To build and export the /out directory which I then upload to my S3 bucket

my next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    target: "serverless"
}
```

I had it like this as I was originally making use of serverless for Next but have since moved away from it as I'm largely making use of client-side rendering and don't need any of the features it was providing and I am still in the process of doing a cleanup on the project.

Answer (score 0):

Routing in S3 is done with exact match of the file name. You can remove .html extension to use routing as you like. And set metadata Content-type to text/html, to view it properly in browser